# Timelines JavaFX

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

How can I add a delay between keyframes? I want the user to see the front of the card for 0.6 seconds before it closes if the cards do not match. Here is the code
I tried the one in the bottom but it doesn't work.

```
KeyFrame start = new KeyFrame(
            Duration.ZERO,
            new KeyValue(imageView.scaleXProperty(), 1.0));
    KeyFrame middle = new KeyFrame(
            Duration.millis(150),
            e -> imageView.setImage(image),
            new KeyValue(imageView.scaleXProperty(), 0.0)
    );
    KeyFrame end = new KeyFrame(
            Duration.millis(300),
            new KeyValue(imageView.scaleXProperty(), 1.0));
    new Timeline(start, middle, end).play();



KeyFrame start = new KeyFrame(
            Duration.ZERO,
            new KeyValue(imageView.scaleXProperty(), 1.0));
    KeyFrame middle = new KeyFrame(
            Duration.millis(150),
            e -> imageView.setImage(image),
            new KeyValue(imageView.scaleXProperty(), 0.0)
    );
    KeyFrame delay = new KeyFrame(
            Duration.millis(600)
    );
    KeyFrame end = new KeyFrame(
            Duration.millis(300),
            new KeyValue(imageView.scaleXProperty(), 1.0));
    new Timeline(start, middle,delay, end).play();
```

Comment: Just add in another `KeyFrame` with the same `KeyValue`.

Comment: I tried to add it between them but since it has no action it didn't work

Comment: It shouldn't need an action to work. It's hard to visualize which frame is doing what here since this isn't the full code. Could you post the code that you attempted?

Comment: Of Course I edited the post

Comment: Make it `new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(600), new KeyFrame(imageView.scaleXProperty(), 0.0));`

Comment: KeyFrame or KeyValue?

Comment: `KeyValue`, typo there.

Comment: It doesn't work it ends up in 0 and disappears

Comment: All the durations are calculated relative to the start of the timeline, so the durations above should be incorrect.

Comment: KeyFrame start = new KeyFrame(
                Duration.millis(700),
                new KeyValue(imageView.scaleXProperty(), 1.0));
        KeyFrame middle = new KeyFrame(
                Duration.millis(850),
                e -> imageView.setImage(image),
                new KeyValue(imageView.scaleXProperty(), 0.0)

        );
        KeyFrame end = new KeyFrame(
                Duration.millis(1000),
                new KeyValue(imageView.scaleXProperty(), 1.0));
        new Timeline(start, middle, end).play();

Comment: This one worked!! thanks

Comment: Apparently the duration here is a little confusing. I hadn't touched JavaFX for about a year and I had totally forgotten about this.

Comment: I see,thank you for your time and energy sir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note:** The below assumes the card is "scaled in" as well as "scaled out". I'm not sure that's actually what you want considering your use of `Duration.ZERO` in the question. If you want the card to just pop up immediately then remove the scale-in animation; simply show the card then start the animation (where the `PauseTransition` is the first in the sequential setup).

---

Use `SequentialTranition`, `PauseTransition`, and `ScaleTransition` to your advantage. For example:

```java
ScaleTransition start = new ScaleTransition(Duration.millis(150));
start.setToX(1.0);

// plays after 'start' finishes
PauseTransition middle = new PauseTransition(Duration.millis(600));

// plays after 'middle' finishes
ScaleTransition end = new ScaleTransition(Duration.millis(300));
end.setToX(0.0);

// only set the node on the SequentialTransition
SequentialTransition animation = new SequentialTransition(imageView, start, middle, end);
```

If you want the scale transitions to have the same duration then the above can be simplified to:

```java
ScaleTransition scale = new ScaleTransition(Duration.millis(150));
scale.setFromX(0.0);
scale.setToX(1.0);

// Set to half the desired time because of the auto-reverse configured below
PauseTransition pause = new PauseTransition(Duration.millis(300));

// Plays 'scale' forwards, followed by 'pause', then plays 'pause' backwards
// followed by `scale`. That's why 'pause' has its duration set to half the full
// desired duration (it's played forwards then immediately backwards for a total
// of 600 ms).
SequentialTransition animation = new SequentialAnimation(imageView, scale, pause);
animation.setAutoReverse(true);
animation.setCycleCount(2);
```

Comment: So I added MouseClick listeners to pictures right, when I click them it opens. If 2 cards are opened and they aren't the same it closes. I want to wait 0.6 seconds after the 2nd card opens and then close it.

Comment: I tried to switch the pause's location to the start

Comment: It actually worked very well, thank you sir

Comment: Glad it's working for you. Note you could also make use of `ParellelTransition` since you're hiding two cards simultaneously (create two `SequentialTransition`s and put them in the `ParellelTransition`).